# Ubuntu shows Debian logo and crashes on boot

Tags: 11.10, boot, kernel, boot-failure

I installed Ubuntu 11.10 today and used it for a few hours. I restarted the computer and in the screen where you chose the kernel version, the screen is not the Ubuntu purple screen anymore - it shows the Debian logo and when you hit Enter it doesn't start.
I tried a fresh reinstall but it happened again.

I beg for help, I'm using Windows to post this (shame on me)

Comment: did you install gnome panel.

Comment: Yes, XFCE and gnome-shell. That could be the cause?

Comment: Because when i install gnome the same had happened with me,Purple screen changed to Debian screen. But the OS is booting properly in my case both Ubuntu and windows 7

Comment: The first and second time it happened, it worked. But after that it started crashing and don't boot anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a fresh installation of Ubuntu 11.10 and update all required packages, then you want you can install gnome-shell and reboot

See weather proper booting or not

Then you install XFCE see weather proper booting or not.

Because when i install gnome the same had happened with me,Purple screen changed to Debian screen. But the OS is booting properly in my case both Ubuntu and windows 7

Just checked out and reply

Comment: I actually did a upgrade... After what you said I thought trying purging the gnome-panel in recovery mode. If that don't work I will try doing what you said. Thanks for the reply.